# RenderTexture.Create failed: format unsupported for random writes - R32 SFloat (49) Unity URP project

Tags: unity-game-engine, directx

When I create a URP project in unity it shows this error in the console saying:

`RenderTexture.Create failed: format unsupported for random writes - R32 SFloat (49). UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)`

And sometimes it shows this error in console too:

`RenderTexture.Create failed: format unsupported for random writes - R32 SFloat (49). UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.UniversalAdditionalCameraData:OnDestroy ()`

However I can run the game with no problem and everything works fine but there is another error like this one that won't go away and it will appear if I do anything in the unity editor:

`Assertion failed on expression: 'SUCCEEDED(hr)'`

It is probably related to DirectX but I don't know what the actual problem is.

Note: I'm using Intel hd graphics 3000 on my old laptop, but on my newer laptop which uses rtx 2070 Max-Q there is no problem obviously and I'm using unity 2022.3.7 LTS. So I guess I should change some of the settings in unity.

And it's also very annoying to see other errors among these pesky ones I mentioned earlier.

But changing the quality of the shaders or anything else doesn't fix these errors (I didn't try all the quality settings for every game object but if you change the quality of the lights and textures it doesn't fix the error as I tried.)

I couldn't find any solution for this problem and I would be grateful if you could help me solve this problem.